# Rails optional belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm writing a Rails frontend for inventory management. I want users to be able to register products, so I have:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
  # <snip>
end
```

and

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  # <snip>
end
```

The problem is that products are created prior to being registered by a user. That is, it's perfectly acceptable to call `Product.create` and just have it set the `user_id` to `nil`. As you can imagine, though, Rails doesn't support this out of the box:

```
> Product.create!
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "products" WHERE "products"."type" IN ('Product')
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: User can't be blank
    from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/validations.rb:56:in `save!'
```

I've thought about a bunch of kludgey workarounds, the most appealing of which is to have a `NullUser` subclassing `User` and use that to create products. But that still seems like a hack. What's the Rails Way with this?

Thanks.

---

The relevant migration:

```
class AddUseridToProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :products, :user_id, :integer
  end
end
```

and later:

```
class Changeuseridtobeoptionalforproducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column :products, :user_id, :integer, null: true
  end
end
```

Comment: Please, post all the validations that you have on the `Product` model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a validation that requires user be present? If so, remove that.

Comment: `belongs_to` require parent object to be present by default on the time of creation. If you'll create a child object without a parent, you will get `["<parent> must exist"]` error message, so your object is not valid. For a solution check @Alexis answer

Answer (score 318):

Just an update for rails 5, if you want this kind of behavior you will need to pass this option:

```
belongs_to :user, optional: true
```

In Rails 5, whenever we define a belongs_to association, it is required to have the associated record present by default.

**Update**
If you still want to use the old behavior by default you can add the configuration to your application.rb file.

```
# /config/application.rb
config.active_record.belongs_to_required_by_default = false
```

***notice:*** there were some [issues](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/23589) on early releases of Rails 5 with this configuration, but is currently fixed, tested on the release candidate **5.2.3**.

Comment: I tried this in rails 5, I see its optional, but the problem is if I enter a non-existing value in foreign key field, it accepts it. In this case it should raise error that its not available in primary table. So how to fix this?

Comment: You can actually do this with any relation, I believe that anything you put would try to do a to_i on it, if it isn't a number or nil. You should be using the instance methods that belong_to provides, creating associations through  this method will prevent incorrect values, use Association.users.build and User.build_association to also avoid non existing records been associated, in my case, where I'm using the optional true is for the associated user to a certain record, this record admits guest users so I'm just doing Association.user = current_user, if current_user is nil i wont get an error

Comment: Worked like a charm for me in `6.0.3.7`! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 6):

Rails absolutely supports this out of the box, check your migrate, have you included a constraint such as `:null => false` on the `user_id` line? If so, take it out!

Edit: Or as @Rodrigo Dias states, reverse it to `:null => true`.

Also, check that you don't have any validations on the user relation in the Product model.

Comment: or just switch to :null => true

Comment: I added my migration to the OP (didn't paste it here since the line breaks would've died).

Comment: I made a migration with `change_column :products, :user_id, :integer, null: true`, but that did nothing.

Comment: What version of Ruby are you on? `null: true` only works after 1.9 I think, try `:null => true` instead

Comment: @tsm try `change_column_null :products, :user_id, true`