# How to prevent multiple queries when updating a record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table `customers` with a couple of belong_to's: a customer belongs to a country, a sector, and a type.

I got the following result, when updating a customer:

```
> Customer.first.update(notes: "Some extra notes")
  Customer Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  `customers`.* FROM `customers` ORDER BY `customers`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  Country Load (1.5ms)  SELECT  `countries`.* FROM `countries` WHERE `countries`.`id` = '26' LIMIT 1
  Sector Load (1.6ms)  SELECT  `sectors`.* FROM `sectors` WHERE `sectors`.`id` = 89 LIMIT 1
  Type Load (1.6ms)  SELECT  `types`.* FROM `types` WHERE `types`.`id` = 8 LIMIT 1
  Customer Update (0.3ms)  UPDATE `customers` SET `notes` = "Some extra notes", `updated_at` = '2019-06-27 08:52:56' WHERE `customers`.`id` = 1
```

I think the extra queries are there to check if the relations are still valid. But it's extremely slow when mass updating all customers. How can I prevent those extra queries?

Comment: try adding `belongs_to :country, optional: true` in your model

Comment: please check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16699877/rails-optional-belongs-to  but this will make belongs_to association as optional in all cases.

Comment: @AbhishekAravindan. Thanks, but it should not be optional. I am looking for something that the database just tries to update/create the record. If it can't, then I get the error anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `update_attribute` instead, that doesn't run any validations on your model.

```
Customer.first.update_attribute(:notes, 'Some extra notes')
```

---

Read more about [`update_attribute`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_attribute) and other nice methods

*Updates a single attribute and saves the record. This is especially useful for boolean flags on existing records. Also note that*

- Validation is skipped.
- Callbacks are invoked.
- updated_at/updated_on column is updated if that column is
  available.
- Updates all the attributes that are dirty in this object.

Comment: Do I have to avoid the validations, the callbacks, or both? What is exactly the difference?

Comment: Take a read thru this, it answers both questions https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html

Answer (score 1):

Your can use update_columns to skip the callbacks if you really sure you don't need it.

try

```
Customer.first.update_columns(notes: "Some extra notes")
```