# has_one association with optional: true?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6, has-one

In a simple booking app:

- When user selects a seat, a `TempAppointment` is created.
- After the seat has been paid for, an Appointment is created based off the info in the TempAppointment record.

The Appointment record cannot be created first, since the passenger may not pay, in which case the TempAppointment stays as-in, and an associated Appointment record never gets created.

My natural thinking is that a TempAppointment has_one Appointment (which works), **but when I add `optional: true`, I see errors**:

```rb
class TempAppointment < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :appointment, optional: true 
end
```

try to create a new TempAppointment

```
ta = TempAppointment.new(cruise_id: 1, passenger_id: 1, start_time: start_time, end_time: start_time + 3600)
ArgumentError: Unknown key: :optional. Valid keys are: :class_name, :anonymous_class, :foreign_key,
 :validate, :autosave, :foreign_type, :dependent, :primary_key, :inverse_of, :required, :as, :touch
```

Why can't `has_one` work with `optional: true`?

Comment: Is their a specific reason you want to have two different tables instead of using a simpler solution like an enum?

Comment: @max tbh I don't know how to solve with an enum. I did consider a simpler solution: add a 'paid' (t/f) column to Appointment and don't even have a TempAppointment table. The problem with that is every existing query on Appointment would then have to have a `.where(paid: t)` so I went with the two-tables approach. Is there somewhere you recommend I can read up on enums?

Comment: https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.4.4/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html

Comment: You have to give `optional: true` in belongs_to model and not in has_one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`has_one` is `optional: true` by default (even if it isn't really an option of this method, I mean has_one never means it is require)

So if you set the optional: true to the other model, be careful, this means that this other model doesn't need to be in a relationship with the first one. It's a one way dependence.

```rb
# your model_a doesn't need any model_b to exist
class ModelA < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :model_b, optional: true
  
  [...]
end

# same for model_b, it can exist without model_a
class ModelB < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :model_a
  
  [...]
end
```

But if you do

```rb
# your model_a has to belong to a model_b, otherwise it will fail
class ModelA < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :model_b
  
  [...]
end

# your model_b can still exist without model_a
class ModelB < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :model_a
  
  [...]
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I switched the model associations around and it worked.

AFAIK, it makes no difference anywhere in the app.

Some helpful hints [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40895199/5783745)

Here's what worked:

```
class Appointment < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :temp_appointment 
end
```

```
class TempAppointment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :appointment, optional: true 
end
```

Answer (score 3):

On the Model where the `has_one` relationship is defined, I think you might be able to use `required: false`. So in the end, it would look something like this:

```
class Appointment < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :temp_appointment, required: false
end
```

```
class TempAppointment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :appointment, optional: true 
end
```

https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_one