# How to delete an object from postgres that is associated to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm using rails as the ruby web framework. I have an object that is associated to another object.
For example:
Let's suppose we are creating a Twitter clone on rails where if we delete a Twitter user, we also delete all their Tweets. That will look something like this:

```rb
class TwitterAcc < ApplicationRecord 
   has_many :tweets, dependent: :destroy
   belongs_to :user
end
```

This code snippet means that if we delete a user's Twitter account, then we should delete all their tweets. How would we delete a Twitter account **without** deleting their tweets?

```rb
class TwitterAcc < ApplicationRecord 
   has_many :tweets
   belongs_to :user
end
```

This code snippet ^^^ wouldn't work. It would throw this error `"ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey"`

Comment: I don't use ROR, but a little searching found this [ROR dependent](https://rubyonrails.org/2006/4/28/associations-arent-dependent-true-anymore). I believe what you are looking for is: "As an aside, another valid option is :dependent => :nullify which is similar to :dependent => :delete_all except rather than deleting the associated records, it just sets their foreign keys to NULL. This effectively removes the association, without removing the associated records from the database table."

Comment: That error is because you have a foreign key constraint at the database level, it doesn't really have anything to do with Rails. If you want to keep the tweets, you'll need to remove that foreign key constraint first.

Comment: This thread covers it also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16699877/rails-optional-belongs-to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that (if things are right) you have a foreign key between your TwitterAcc table and the tweets. So one tweet record CANOT have a tweeter_acc_id that is not existing. Which is the case if you try to destroy the tweeter_acc. And PSQL isn't happy with that

So you have multiple choices:

- or you allow your tweets table to keep record of the twitter_acc id, but then you need to remove the foreign key (which is IMO not a good idea)
- or you allow your tweets table to have a nil value on tweets#twitted_acc_id (+ you may need a `belongs_to :tweet_acc, optional: true` on your Tweet model) and use `has_many :tweets, dependent: :nullify` on your `TweeterAcc` model
- or you only soft delete your tweeter account model, so a soft deleted record becomes "invisible" for your application business logic, but you don't need to deal with the nullable or inexisting FK (https://github.com/jhawthorn/discard)

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly right. I should have closed this question yesterday, but `dependent: :nullify` was exactly what I needed. Basically, I want to just set the foreign key to null if the object it is referring has been deleted; otherwise it has a relationship with something non-existent so it rolls back. Thank you for answering this question. Hopefully this answer will help others who might have this issue.

Comment: Glad it helped!
don't hesitate to mark it as valid answer and close the question then @DavidEm-Yinn ;)